# yum equivalent of "apt-get purge"

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, package-management

I want to reinstall a package on CentOS and start from scratch. In Debian, I can do a `apt-get purge foo` and it'll remove all config files for foo. `yum remove foo` doesn't remove the config files. Is there any way to do `apt-get purge foo` using yum?

Comment: Note that the only reason for apt-get purge is because apt-get remove leaves config. files in place, yum remove does not do that (they are moved to .rpmsave files if they have been changed, in fact it will even tell you it's doing so).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do

```
yum remove package
yum install package
```

on command line. If there is any config file which is not replaced during installation then message will be printed on screen that the file has been saved with different name. Move new file to old file.

This is hoping there are very less configuration files of package which you are trying to re-install.

Comment: Not really. This does not remove config files

Comment: Does not print a message for me.

Answer (score 10):

Not terribly elegant, but it works:

```
for package in package1 package2 package3
do
  echo "removing config files for $package"
  for file in $(rpm -q --configfiles $package)
  do
    echo "  removing $file"
    rm -f $file
  done
  rpm -e $package
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`rpm -e <package-name>` will do the trick if it's still available